# Why are using these pygame imports giving me an error?

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to python so I apologize for the likely stupidity behind this question.

I have two files that I am using - `File1` and `File2`

Within `File1` I have variable `X` defined, this file alters the value of `X` throughout my game and imports specific objects from `File2`

Within `File2` I have the line `from File1 import X` without using the variable at all within that File.

Hitting run comes up with an error stating that it cannot import a function from File2:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'draw_panel' from partially initialized module 'File2' (most likely due to a circular import)`

If instead of importing specific objects including that one from `File1` like i was previously doing, I was to simply type `from File2 import *` then my game would run for a short while until producing the following error:

`NameError: name 'draw_panel' is not defined`

I apologize for the vague structure of this question, I am open to any alternative suggestions on importing. I simply need to be able to use the variable that is also altered within the first File.

Comment: about the circular import: You import a file so importing runs the file and while running the file it tries importing the module that is running this files but the file has not done importing if You get what I am saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of importing `x` from `File1` directly, you can pass a variable to a function from `File2` the variable `x`.

To accomplish this, you would need to execute the code from `File2` within `File1`, which would be most easily accomplished by setting up a class in `File2` which contains all your functions and variables needed.

For a very basic example:

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test_variable = 2

    def multiply_test_variable(self, x):
        self.test_variable *= x
```

Then, import this class in `File1` and run the code from there:

```
from File2 import TestClass

x = 3

test_object = TestClass()

print(test_object.test_variable)
test_object.multiply_test_variable(x)
print(test_object.test_variable)
```

It's hard to explain or give examples without your actual code but I hope this helps make it somewhat clear what I mean.